# Showing disable developer mode popup using selenium in vba

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, vba

```
Dim bot As New WebDriver

bot.Start "Chrome", "http://google.com"

bot.Get "/"
```

Its opening chrome but chrome shows disable developer mode extension popup.

Comment: Please provide a bit more context for your question and describe the problem clearer.

Answer (score 0):

With the [chrome options](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) capabilities you can control a lot of properties. On Java I use something like that to disable the extensions:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--disable-extensions",
            "--disable-autofill-keyboard-accessory-view", "test-type");
    Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
    prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    capabilities.setCapability("elementScrollBehavior", 1);
```

if you find the way to control the capabilities with VBa, you got it.